# Isomorphisms in tangent bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, tangent-bundle

Given the tangent bundle $T$, is the following isomorphism $$\Lambda^{d-1}T\simeq T^*\otimes\Lambda^dT^* $$
true on a $d$-dimensional manifold? i.e. are $(d-1)$-vectors equivalent to objects which are tensor products of a 1 form and a $d$ form? And if so, why?

Comment: You probably mean $\wedge^{d-1}T\cong T^{*}\otimes\wedge^{d}T$. This is correct. For the transition matrices note that the transition matrices for $T^{*}$ are $(g_{\alpha,\beta}^t)^{-1}$ which can be calculated using the $\det(g_{\alpha,\beta})$ and the matrix of (signed) $(d-1)\times(d-1)$ minors of $g_{\alpha,\beta}$.

Comment: @didier Your first $1$ should be $d$, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. The wedge product
$$ \wedge \colon \Lambda^{d - 1}(V) \times V \rightarrow \Lambda^n(V) $$
gives you a non-degenerate pairing as one can easily verify by choosing a basis for $V$. This means that we have a canonical isomorphism
$$ \Lambda^{d-1}(V) \xrightarrow{\varphi} \operatorname{Hom}_k(V, \Lambda^d(V)) $$
given by $\varphi(\alpha)(v) = \alpha \wedge v$. Since $\operatorname{Hom}_k(V, \Lambda^d(V))$ is isomorphic to $V^{*} \otimes \Lambda^d(V)$ you get an isomorphism
$\Lambda^{d-1}(V) \cong V^{*} \otimes \Lambda^d(V)$. If $V$ is equipped with a volume form (a non-zero element of $\Lambda^d(V^{*})$) then the volume form gives you an identification between $\Lambda^d(V)$ and $\Lambda^d(V^{*})$ so you also get an isomorphism $\Lambda^{d-1}(V) \cong V^{*} \otimes \Lambda^d(V^{*})$.

---

This generalizes fiberwise to manifolds. Without any assumptions on $M$ you have a canonical isomorphism of vector bundles $\Lambda^{d-1}(TM) \cong T^{*}M \otimes \Lambda^d(TM)$. If $M$ is oriented by a volume-form $\omega$ then you get an ($\omega$-dependent) isomorphism $\Lambda^{d-1}(TM) \cong T^{*}M \otimes \Lambda^d(T^{*}M)$. If you follow all the identifications involved, you can write this isomorphism succintly as
$$ \alpha \mapsto \iota_{\alpha}(\omega) \otimes \omega $$
where $\iota_{\alpha}(\omega)$ is the one-form obtained from $\omega$ by contracting it with the multivector $\alpha$.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks a lot.